# Mithril: Wrapping children in an array when using jsx

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, mithril.js

I'm so close to getting jsx to work with mithril.

However, mithril wants you to wrap child elements in an array. It doesn't show a jsx example more than one element deep in the mithril documentation.

So a mithril component such as

```
'use strict'

import m from 'mithril';

export default m.Component = {
    view () {
        return (
            <div className={'xxxx'}>
                <div className={'xxxx'}>
                    <div className={'xxxxx'}>
                        <h2>xxxxx</h2>
                        <p>xxxxxx</p>
                        <p>xxxxxx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

yields the error message

```
Mithril v1.0.0 only supports 3 arguments, wrap children in an array.
```

and the component fails to render. It worked when I just had the header and no paragraph elements. How can I wrap the three elements in an array in a way jsx will parse?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `divs` and such in an array if you wrap them in curly braces, like so:

```
...
  return (
     <div className={'xxxx'}>
        <div className={'xxxx'}>
          <div className={'xxxxx'}>
          { [
            <h2>xxxxx</h2>,
            <p>xxxxxx</p>,
            <p>xxxxxx</p>
          ] }
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>,
  )
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. The array must be on the middle three elements. The comma at the end of your list led me to the solution.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was the commas between list elements.

```
        return (
            <div className={'xxxx'}>
                <div className={'xxxxx'}>
                    <div className={'xxxx'}>
                        {[
                            <h2>xxx</h2>, // Comma here
                            <p>xxxx</p>, // Comma here
                            <p>xxxx</p>
                        ]}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```